# JTA coming to OrientDB 2.2.x?

Tags: orientdb

Are there any plans to support JTA for OrientDB 2.2.x, so it can be integrated in full-featured transactional JEE app servers like Wildfly? Looking at the OPS4J integration module, it explicitly avoids JTA as not suported...

Answer (score 0):

This link '[new features 2.2](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/Roadmap.html)' shows all the new functionality included in the 2.2, in which nothing appears on the "distributed transaction".